# How can I PM people on this site?

Tags: support, private-messaging

Couldn't find it anywhere on user profile page. How can I reach some people who just answered my question for some details?

Comment: The 50 rep requirement does not apply for an asker to comment on answers to his own questions.

Answer (score 8):

In your case, your best option is to simply add a comment to their answer. They will see a little notification when they log in next.

---

But, for all the details ...

There is no built-in messaging system as it was decided that StackOverflow should be specifically for Q&A, not social networking.

However, you can do one of the following to contact a user:

- Comment on one of their questions
- Comment on one of their answers
- If they have commented somewhere, reply with your own comment, and reference their name like @

  - Specifically, the first user in descending order of comment reply time who matches the first three letters of your @name is notified of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You reply under their answers.  They'll get a notification of this shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Leave comments on their answers.

Answer (score 2):

if PM stands for Private Message (or similar) there is no way to do it. (comments are not private...)
Only hope is that the person has some contact information (e-mail, ICQ, ...) on his profile.

If you want details about an answer or question it is better to use comments instead of being "private", someone else could need the same details.

Answer (score 1):

Some users write their email address on their profile page. If they do this it means that you can send private messages to them via email. If they do not provide a contact address it most likely means that they do not want to receive private messages.