# PM - requesting a person

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I PM people on this site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/how-can-i-pm-people-on-this-site)

Is it possible to request the person by PM?

Senario:
1. Someone asked a question
2. He is asked to show the code
3. The code was used unfortunately in pastebin.com
4. 1 week later session expired pastebin.com code is gone

5. Possible to request by PM a person if he would like to allow me to check that? if not he can just ignore me, we respect that.

Thank you

Comment: You can address them in a comment (just like I did here) which will alert them to your response the next time they load a page, but there's no 'private' means of messaging them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no PM function in Stack Overflow.

You can leave a comment to contact the person.

Comment: You are right, but when the question is answered, nobody anymore allowed to put "Comments", we can put answers only.

Comment: I cant leave a comment, that feature is not active for me! for example this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617984/error-compiling-simple-pjsip-program-under-ubuntu

Comment: Disregard PMs; acquire reputation.

Comment: @StackFan: Once you have the requisite reputation (all of 50) you can comment on most posts, including those that are closed and those that have an accepted answer.

Comment: @dmckee So, how can a person with reputation lower than 50 to leave message to a person?

Comment: @user1995781 They can't.