# How do I ask <user> why they made revision <Revision URL>?

Tags: support, comment-replies, revisions-list, private-messaging

And more specifically for me, how do I ask https://stackoverflow.com/users/14065/martin why they made revision https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5995944/revisions?

(I don't *mind* the revision, but am interested in why exactly)

Comment: As for a reason, the removed text was more of commentary and not relevant to the question itself.

Comment: Many SO members are against any hint of social behaviour and want only dry facts. No "hello" no "thanks" and god forbidden, no rants. Take it or leave it, that's how it is. (For the record, I'm not one of them, but can't really change how SO works)

Comment: See also: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and its answers.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are really the only way of doing so, as [there is no PM functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/how-can-i-pm-people-on-this-site) (nor will there be).  Anyone who has revised a post is a valid target <sup>[(source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him)</sup> for [@replies via comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), so any @reply comment on your post will land in their inbox.

Further (though it doesn't seem to apply here), if you feel someone made a bad revision, you can always roll it back by simply finding the revision you want to roll back to and clicking the "rollback" link.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him).